# Assigning an object inside a called method, after passing it as parameter, has no effect in the calling method

Tags: java

I have a problem with the modification or more like assignment of an object which is passed to sub-methods. There is a Cost object, which only has some double variables to hold certain values.

```
public class Cost {
    double insertCost = 0;
    double deleteEleCost = 0;  

    private void addInsertCost(double cost) {
        insertCost += checkCost(cost);
    }

    private void addDeleteCost(double cost) {
        deleteEleCost += checkCost(cost);
    }

    public double getInsertCost() {
        return insertCost;
    }

    public double getDeleteCost() {
        return deleteEleCost;
    }

    public double getTotalCost() {
        return insertCost + deleteEleCost;
    }
}
```

In The following after calcAverageCost() is finished, the values of Cost cost are always 0, although in the method calcAverageCost() the values for the passed Cost object are greater than 0 (calculated):

```
private Cost handleCase1(Content content1, Content content2, Cost cost) {
    calcAverageCost(content1, content2, cost);
    System.out.println("insert: " + cost.getInsertCost());
    System.out.println("delete: " + cost.getDeleteCost());
    return cost;
}
```

In calcAverageCost() the Method getCost() calculates cost based on the two Content objects. For the example, those are not important, the thing is, that the new 6 single Cost objects for every aspect of the two Contents do in fact carry some values for insertCost and deleteCost each after puttung them into getCost().

These 6 smaller Cost objects get merged into 3 bigger ones. Even those hold values as expected.
As a final step, getMinCost() (see at the end) returns the one Cost object with the smallest costvalues and assigns this to the new Cost object finalCost. Then, this object is assigned to the passed Cost object (cost) from above. Even after those two actions, the modified double variables are printed out nicely for finalCost as well as Cost cost. But when the method calcAverageCost() ends and the method from above handleCase1() continues, the passed Cost cost once again only contains 0s in there variables, like nothing happened during the alteration in calcAverageCost().

From my understanding, there should be one internal object in Java, which is the result of the getMinCost() method. By assigning finalCost to it, this internal object is pointed at from that one Cost object. And by doing the same for Cost cost, this one should point there too. But somehow, this effect doesn't carry over to the original caller method? Do I have a misconception here? I thought this was like how Java worked.

I remember a balloon thread here on Stackoverflow, as well as many other threads regarding pass-by-value and Java. Normally I try to just read threads, this is the first time I can't wrap my head around a problem, so I dediced to ask the question...

I would really appreciate any help, and sorry if this question is a bad question.

```
private void calcAverageCost(Content content1, Content content2, Cost cost){
    Cost min_min = new Cost();
    Cost min_max = new Cost();
    Cost avg_min = new Cost();
    Cost avg_max = new Cost();
    Cost max_min = new Cost();
    Cost max_max = new Cost();

    getCost(content1, content2,min_min);
    getCost(content1, content2,min_max);
    getCost(content1, content2,avg_min);
    getCost(content1, content2,avg_max);
    getCost(content1, content2,max_min);
    getCost(content1, content2,max_max);

    System.out.println("step1");
    printCost(min_min);
    printCost(min_max);
    printCost(avg_min);
    printCost(avg_max);
    printCost(max_min);
    printCost(max_max);
    //These one prints out nicely

    Cost s_min = new Cost();
    Cost s_avg = new Cost();
    Cost s_max = new Cost();

    s_min.addInsertCost((min_min.getInsertCost()+min_max.getInsertCost())/2d);
    s_min.addDeleteCost((min_min.getDeleteCost()+min_max.getDeleteCost())/2d);
    s_avg.addInsertCost((avg_min.getInsertCost()+avg_max.getInsertCost())/2d);
    s_avg.addDeleteCost((avg_min.getDeleteCost()+avg_max.getDeleteCost())/2d);
    s_max.addInsertCost((max_min.getInsertCost()+max_max.getInsertCost())/2d);
    s_max.addDeleteCost((max_min.getDeleteCost()+max_max.getDeleteCost())/2d);

    System.out.println("step2");
    printCost(s_min);
    printCost(s_avg);
    printCost(s_max);
    //These one prints out nicely as well

    Cost finalCost = getMinCost(getMinCost(s_min,s_avg),s_max);
    printCost(finalCost);
    //Also this one prints out nicely
    cost = finalCost;
    printCost(cost);
    //Even this one prints out nicely
}
```

Here is the getMinCost() method, it just compares two Cost objects and returns the one with the better variables

```
private Cost getMinCost(Cost cost1, Cost cost2) {
    Cost cost = cost1;
    System.out.println("cost1:"+cost1.getTotalCost());
    System.out.println("cost2:"+cost2.getTotalCost());
    if (cost1.getTotalCost() < cost2.getTotalCost()) {
        cost = cost1;
        System.out.println("cost1smaller");
    } else if (cost1.getTotalCost() > cost2.getTotalCost()) {
        cost = cost2;
        System.out.println("cost2smaller");
    } else if (cost1.getTotalCost() == cost2.getTotalCost()) {
        if (cost1.getDeleteCost() < cost2.getDeleteCost()) {
            cost = cost1;
            System.out.println("cost1delsmaller");
        } else if (cost1.getDeleteCost() > cost2.getDeleteCost()) {
            cost = cost2;
            System.out.println("cost2delsmaller");
        } else if (cost1.getDeleteCost() == cost2.getDeleteCost()) {
            cost = cost1;
            System.out.println("cost1deleq");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("cost:"+cost.getTotalCost());
    //shows correct result so far, the minimum cost
    return cost;
}
```

Comment: That was a really roundabout way of asking whether Java is pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. And the answer is: [Java is pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: What @biziclop is referring to means that that the line cost = finalCost; will only change the reference to cost _inside_ the method and won't affect the cost reference in the calling context. So after the calcAverageCost method is called in handleCase1 the cost reference will still point to the same object and the changes that exist in finalCost won't reflect.

Comment: Thank you both. So the parameter-cost reference was also just a kind of "copy" of the original cost reference. I guess that's what meant with "references are passed-by-value too". I originally thought I understood that concept, but it seems not. I've learned something for life, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic "pass by reference" behavior, in order to modify the input cost, use a holder mutable object:

```
public class Holder<T> {
  private T value;
  public void setValue(T value) {this.value = value;}
  public T getValue() {return this.value;}
}
```

And have:

```
private void calcAverageCost(Content content1, Content content2, Holder<Cost> holder) {
  ...
  holder.setValue(finalCost);
}
```

Or, since there is only one parameter to change:

```
private Cost calcAverageCost(Content content1, Content content2, final Cost cost) {
  ...
  return finalCost;
}
```

And use the returned value from calling code. This would be better (you should avoid mutating the parameters of a method).

Comment: Ahh... I feel so stupid now. So, the only thing I had to do was e. g. cost.addInsertCost(finalCost.getInsertCost()) instead of assigning it. But a Holder<T> class might be an even better solution, thank you very much.
May I ask why it is bad to mutate parameters? Do you mean it from a best-practice or from a technical perspective?

Comment: It is more from best practice than from a technical perspective. I suppose your pasted code here is a code meant for a business rather than for a framework: in this case (business), you should keep it simple and obvious to achieve greater maintainability. Note that in Scala, immutability is encouraged, and I think it is better to try to also achieve that as much as possible in Java: immutable objects are _normally_ thread safe.